# Derivation in paper Deep Neural Networks as Gaussian processes in ICLR 2018

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, machine-learning, neural-networks, gaussian

I am trying to understand the derivation of the main equation in the seminal paper titled [Deep Neural Networks as Gaussian processes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00165) (in ICLR 2018).  Following is the equation number (7), which can be found on page 5 of the paper :

$$
\require{cancel}
P(z^{*}\mid D, x^{*}) = \int P(z^{*}\mid z,x,x^{*})P(z\mid D)dz = \frac{1}{P(t)}\int P(z^{*},z\mid x,x^{*})P(t\mid z)dz$$

When I try to derive it myself I obtain the following result:

$$
\begin{split}
P(z^{*}\mid D, x^{*}) &= \int P(z^{*}, z\mid D,x^{*})dz\\
                  &= \int P(z^{*} \mid z,D,x^{*})P(z\mid D,x^{*})dz \\
                  &= \int P(z^{*} \mid z,D,x^{*})P(z\mid D)dz  \hspace{1in} \text{Since $z$ is indpendent of $x^{*}$}.\\
                  &= \int P(z^{*} \mid z,x,t,x^{*})P(z\mid x,t)dz  \hspace{1in} \text{Since $D=(x,t)$.  }\\
                  &= \int P(z^{*} \mid z,t,x,x^{*})P(z\mid t,x)dz  \hspace{1in} \text{Just re-arranging variables}\\
                  &= \int \frac{P(z^{*},z,t\mid x,x^{*})}{\cancel{P(z,t\mid x,x^{*})}} \frac{\cancel{P(z,t\mid x)}}{P(t\mid x)} dz \hspace{1in} \text{Both $z,t$ are independent of $x^{*}$} \\
                  &= \int \frac{P(z^{*},z,t\mid x,x^{*})}{P(t\mid x)} dz \\
                  &= \int \frac{P(z^{*},z\mid x,x^{*})P(t\mid z^{*},z,x,x^{*})}{P(t\mid x)} dz \hspace{1in} \text{expanding the numerator}\\
                  &= \int \frac{P(z^{*},z\mid x,x^{*})P(t\mid z)}{P(t\mid x)} dz \hspace{1in} \text{$t$ is independent of the others given $z$}
\end{split}$$

This result differs from what authors have obtained in the paper.  I have $P(t\mid x)$ in the denominator instead of $P(t)$.

Can anyone please provide some clue where my derivation went wrong?